# Chromium browser - Native Messaging Example issue

Tags: chrome-native-messaging

I am trying the same example given in the link below

http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/common/extensions/docs/examples/api/nativeMessaging/

using Chromium browser 25 on Fedora 17

As explained I am loading the app on Chromium browser and getting the same error as above.

When I see Chrome://Version it does not show me Enable-Native-Messaging option.
also Chrome://Flags does not have the option to enable the Native Messaging.

I am getting this error

> Uncaught Type Error: Object # has no method "ConnectNative"

Is the error is because of the Chromium browser version 25 which I am using on Fedora 17 ?

If yes then where can I get the Chromium browser version on Fedora which supports Native-Messaging-API , If not what could be the issue and the relevant steps to resolve it?